# Huggingface Trainer(): K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: python, cross-validation, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, k-fold

I am following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tuning-pretrained-nlp-models-with-huggingfaces-trainer-6326a4456e7b) from TowardsDataScience for text classification using Huggingface Trainer.
To get a more robust model I want to do a K-Fold Cross Validation, but I am not sure how to do this with Huggingface Trainer.
Is there a built-in feature from Trainer or how can you do the cross-validation here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is not to write your own dataset readers from scratch, as this tutorial does, but to use the [Hugging Face datasets library](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/index), which is already integrated with Hugging Face transformers.

Here is a step-by-step guide on how to adapt the tutorial to the datasets library:

First, we have to turn the original CSV from the tutorial into something that can be loaded with the load_dataset function. We are going to preprocess the original `train.csv` CSV and save the files `new_train.csv` and `validation.csv`.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
data["label"] = data["sentiment"]
train, validation = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)
train.to_csv("new_train.csv")
validation.to_csv("validation.csv")
```

The [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.12.0/en/loading#slice-splits) provides an example on how to create your own cross-validation splits. Here we adapt it to our use case:

```py
val_ds = datasets.load_dataset("csv", data_files={"validation": "validation.csv"}, split=[f"validation[{k}%:{k+10}%]" for k in range(0, 100, 10)])
train_ds = datasets.load_dataset("csv", data_files={"train": "new_train.csv"}, split=[f"train[:{k}%]+train[{k+10}%:]" for k in range(0, 100, 10)])
```

Now we tokenize the splits:

```py
def preprocess_function(examples):
    # Tokenize the texts
    args = ((examples["review"],))
    result = tokenizer(*args, padding=True, max_length=128, truncation=True)
    result["label"] = examples["label"]
    return result

for idx, item in enumerate(train_ds):
    train_ds[idx] = train_ds[idx].map(
        preprocess_function,
        batched=True,
        desc="Running tokenizer on dataset",
    )

for idx, item in enumerate(val_ds):
    val_ds[idx] = val_ds[idx].map(
        preprocess_function,
        batched=True,
        desc="Running tokenizer on dataset",
    )
```

After that, you simply have to loop over the splits and pass them to your `Trainer`.

```py
for train_dataset, val_dataset in zip(train_ds, val_ds):
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=val_dataset,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
        callbacks=[EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3)],
    )
...
```